# why we specify host in /Http header as we already know?

Tags: http, networking, tcp

we know that we use tcp in http. In tcp connection Origin and destination are specify.according to this sentence why we specify host in Http header? 
for example:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www-net.cs.umass.edu\r\n
User-Agent: Firefox/3.6.10\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml\r\n
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7\r\n
Keep-Alive: 115\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
\r\n
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a host in the TCP header. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure for the TCP header.

Comment: sorry. I edit my question

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is specified is to specify the *name* of the host.  Since the request itself is made to the IP address in the IP header, the web server has no real way to know which domain was requested.

Under HTTP 1.0, this was not needed.  After HTTP 1.0 was in existence for a number of years, the prevalence of virtual hosts become very common.  Virtual hosting, in case you are unaware, allows you to host multiple sites on a single server, even the same IP, responding to each domain differently.

Since virtual hosting had become very common, the HTTP 1.1 standard made the `Host` header a requirement, simplifying the logic necessary to figure out which site the request should be routed to.